# Bolyerine Snakes maxillary bone, split?

Tags: anatomy, bone-biology

**How is the maxillary bone split in the Bolyerine Snakes described in T.H Frazzetta's "From Hopeful Monsters to Bolyerine Snakes?"**

In T. H. Frazzetta, "From Hopeful Monsters to Bolyerine Snakes?" He describes boid snakes on the island of Mauritius as being unique among snakes in that they had a split jaw, connected by a joint. This was said to be an example of how continuous evolution could not be true for all cases, as what is the point of 1/2 of jaw, according to Stephen J Gould.

I dont seem to understand the pictures illustrated in the aritcle though, and how the maxillary bone is split and where it is connected to a joint. I could not find a legible picture of a  Bolyerine Snake described like this, if anyone could help with understanding it with a picture that would be appreciated.

I would provide the pictures, but I am not sure if that counts as plagiarism.

Citation:

Published by: The University of Chicago Press for The American Society of Naturalists,
Available from: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2459073

Comment: What figure(s) are you having trouble with in the paper?

Comment: @kmm              I cant find the figures pertaining to the Bolyerine Snakes that label the "split" in the maxillary bone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at Fig. 2 in the paper, the bottom jaw has the split maxillary bone. Do you see how it says "MX" with two lines, instead of "MX" with 1 line on the top skull from Fig. 2? Each of those lines go to part of the split maxilla, with the joint being where it is pinched off (between teeth 5 and 6 on the drawing). There is also a CT image of the skull somewhere online that I've run across a few times (actually saw your question while looking for that image now).

I would also amend your statement a little in that it is not "as what is the point of 1/2 of jaw", it is that you can't have 1/2 of the joint(or split bone) existing. Either the maxilla is 1 piece or it is 2, but you cannot gradually go from 1 bone to 2 (similarly, either the cartilage of the joint exists or it doesn't. There can be a gradual change in how much cartilage there is, but if it's there or not is a binary question).

I hope that helps, off to look for the CT scan!

Comment: Nice answer - welcome to Biology.SE! The second part of your answer might be better as a comment on the question, which only asks about the interpretation of the figure.